# Show error page on failure to load ng-view template

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ngroute

I'd like to be able to show a standard error page or template if a template cannot be loaded using `ngRoute`.

I have read that subscribing to `$routeChangeError` can help but unsure where to go from here.

```
$rootScope.$on("$routeChangeError", function (event, current, previous, rejection){
    // somehow tell the routing engine to load my error page (404 or 500 or something)
});
```

Also, can this be done globally or does it have to be done on a per controller basis.  Currently my website isnt fully SPA, it has "silos" of SPA / routing as I slowly convert the site from jQuery to Angular.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably want to redirect your user when hitting an error. As by using your code:

```
$rootScope.$on("$routeChangeError", function (event, current, previous, rejection){
    $location.url('/error');
});
```

And then in your $routeProvider (maybe $stateProvider depending on what you are using), do something like the following

```
$routeProvider
    .when('/error', {
        templateUrl: 'error.html',
        controller: 'YourErrorController'
    })
```